# How to read byte by byte in USB communication?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, usb

I would like to do with USB connection something like in the following code with Bluetooth connection:

```
public void run() {
        byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream 1024
        int bytes=0; // bytes returned from read()

        while (true){
            buffer = new byte[1];


            try {

            for (int i=0; i<responseLength;i++) {

                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                result[i] = buffer[0];

            }

            mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.READ, bytes, -1, result)
                    .sendToTarget();
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                while (mmInStream.available()>0){
                    mmInStream.read(buffer);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

This code for BT reads *responseLength* times 1 byte because every time I exactly know, how long will be the message I get.

I have tried to write a code like this for USB connection, but my problem is, that while Bluetooth  acts like a pipe, so what have been sent,  that I can read byte by byte, in case of USB connection I haven't been able to read byte by byte, because the message disappeared, I had to read it in bigger parts.

So this is my code for USB communication what I have so far:

```
static byte[] readBytes = new byte[4096];
...

r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            reading=true;
            synchronized (this) {
                while (reading) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(400);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Arrays.fill(readBytes, (byte) 0);


                    if (mUsbManager!=null && mUsbManager.hasPermission(device)){


                        recvBytes = connection.bulkTransfer(epIn, readBytes, readBytes.length, 0);
                        if (recvBytes != 2) {
                            readString = new String(readBytes);
                            readString = readString.replace("\u0001`","");
                            readString = readString.replace("\u0000","");

                            if (!readString.equals("")){
                                Message message = handler2.obtainMessage();

                                message.obj = readString;
                                handler2.sendMessage(message);


                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    };
    thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
```

Could you help me, how to write a code for USB reading, which works like a queue or pipe like in Bluetooth communication?

**EDIT**

I have tried another code:

```
while (true){
            readBytes = new byte[1]; 


                for (int i=0; i<responseLength;i++) {

                recvBytes = connection.bulkTransfer(epIn, readBytes, readBytes.length, 100);

                Log.e("bbb", "!" + (new String(readBytes)) + "!" + recvBytes + " " + i);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        }
```

and the Log gives me infinitely something like this:

```
02-10 13:24:42.210 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 0
02-10 13:24:42.261 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 1
02-10 13:24:42.312 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 2
02-10 13:24:42.362 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 3
02-10 13:24:42.412 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 4
02-10 13:24:42.463 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 5
02-10 13:24:42.513 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 6
02-10 13:24:42.564 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 7
02-10 13:24:42.614 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 8
02-10 13:24:42.665 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 9
02-10 13:24:42.716 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 10
02-10 13:24:42.766 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 11
02-10 13:24:42.817 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 12
02-10 13:24:42.867 14602-14755/? E/bbb: !����������������������������!-1 13
```

Comment: Dont understand what you mean by queue or pipe. But if you want to read one bye at a time then change `, readBytes.length,` to `, 1,`.

Comment: `bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);`. If you want to read one byte at a time you dont need a buffer. `int byte = mmInStream.read();`

Comment: i have edited my question. I mean queue or pipe as in case of mmInStream.read(); because it reads just the received bytes and then stops/waits but in case of usb communication it loops forever with the log as you can see in the edited part of my question.

Comment: `because it reads just the received bytes` ? Do you mean: 'it just reads the sent bytes'?

Comment: Yes sorry, my english is not perfect.